# equalsIgnoreCase doesn't conform to javadoc?

Tags: java

The javadoc for `String.equalsIgnoreCase` says:

> Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case.
>   Two characters c1 and c2 are considered the same ignoring case if at least one of the following is true:
>
> The two characters are the same (as compared by the == operator)
>
> Applying the method Character.toUpperCase(char) to each character produces the same result
>
> Applying the method Character.toLowerCase(char) to each character produces the same result

So can anyone explain this?

```
public class Test
{
    private static void testChars(char ch1, char ch2) {
        boolean b1 = (ch1 == ch2 ||
                   Character.toLowerCase(ch1) == Character.toLowerCase(ch2) ||
                   Character.toUpperCase(ch1) == Character.toUpperCase(ch2));
        System.out.println("Characters match: " + b1);

        String s1 = Character.toString(ch1);
        String s2 = Character.toString(ch2);
        boolean b2 = s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2);
        System.out.println("equalsIgnoreCase returns: " + b2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        testChars((char)0x0130, (char)0x0131);
        testChars((char)0x03d1, (char)0x03f4);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Characters match: false
equalsIgnoreCase returns: true
Characters match: false
equalsIgnoreCase returns: true
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using for compile/run? Are these Georgian alphabet letters?

Comment: See this, I think this is related: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/i18n-dev/2011-August.txt

Comment: This is know problem with turkish letters, look here: http://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding, 'Turkish i/I etc.'

Comment: JRE 7 (`java -version` says `1.7.0_03`).  No, they're not Georgian.  One's a Turkish dotless "i" thing and the other has do to with alternative forms of Greek theta.

Comment: Java 8 still buggy, and the document is not fixed either.

Comment: Java is designed for BMP, it makes anything above BMP a mess.

Comment: However it doesn't do BMP well either.

Answer (score 3):

Those characters' defintion of upper and lower case is probably locale-specific. From the JavaDoc for `Character.toLowerCase()`:

> In general, String.toLowerCase() should be used to map characters to
>   lowercase. String case mapping methods have several benefits over
>   Character case mapping methods. String case mapping methods can
>   perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M
>   character mappings, whereas the Character case mapping methods cannot.

If you look at the `String.toLowerCase()` method you will find it overridden to accept a `Locale` object as well. This will perform a locale-specific case conversion.

Edit: I would like to be clear that yes, the JavaDoc for `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` says what it says, but it is wrong. It cannot be correct in all cases, certainly not for characters that have surrogates, for example, but also for characters where the locale defines upper/lower case.

Comment: (1) I'm not using `String.toLowerCase()`; (2) since the doc says that `String.toLowerCase()` is locale-sensitive but `Character.toLowerCase()` isn't, I don't see how your first sentence could be right; (3) even if the definition is deficient, I'd still expect the method to function according to the definition, and it appears not to be.

Comment: My point is that string conversion is locale-aware while character conversion is not. And like my edit says, the JavaDoc is provably incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I found this in `String.java` (this snippet is also in a document that peter.petrov linked to):

```
        if (ignoreCase) {
            // If characters don't match but case may be ignored,
            // try converting both characters to uppercase.
            // If the results match, then the comparison scan should
            // continue.
            char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
            char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
            if (u1 == u2) {
                continue;
            }
            // Unfortunately, conversion to uppercase does not work properly
            // for the Georgian alphabet, which has strange rules about case
            // conversion.  So we need to make one last check before
            // exiting.
            if (Character.toLowerCase(u1) == Character.toLowerCase(u2)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

It's used by `equalsIgnoreCase`.  What's interesting is that if it followed what the javadoc said, the line toward the bottom should be

```
            if (Character.toLowerCase(c1) == Character.toLowerCase(c2)) {
```

using `c1` and `c2` instead of `u1` and `u2`.  This affects the result for these two cases.  We can all agree that the javadoc is "wrong" in that it doesn't really reflect how case-folding should work; but the above logic doesn't deal with correct case-folding any better, and it doesn't conform to the documentation besides.